# Intellij debugging tomcat

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7, remote-debugging, intellij-14

I know this has been asked a few times already but none of the posted solutions seem to help.  I'm trying to debug an application deployed on Tomcat installed locally.

Starting tomcat with these options:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 %JAVA_OPTS%
```

Created a remote debug configuration (NOT tomcat remote) and connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1 on port 8000.  I get this error:

> Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8000): java.io.IOException
>   "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

I should mention that I have done this same setup many times before and never faced any issue.  No idea why this is happening now.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also, I do see that Tomcat is getting started with port 8000 opened.  It's just Intellij which is having trouble connecting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok solved it.  For some reason localhost/127.0.0.1 were not working.  So i tried the full host name and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me too!  Mac os x 10.11.1, Intellij Idea 15. Wouldn't connect (same error message) using either localhost or 127.0.0.1 for "Remote Connection Settings"/"Host:"

Comment: What full host name referring here? Because i am facing the same issue and not able to come out of the error.

Comment: If you're on Windows, see the instructions here to figure out your hostname: https://kb.iu.edu/d/avza

Comment: what do you mean by full host name?

Comment: @thenakulchawla If on windows, I provided the link above.  If on linux/mac then type `hostname` in terminal

Comment: this did not work on me. `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or the `hostname` value did not work

Answer (score 0):

To scale across multiple machines, you can leave the Host field value blank and just fill in the port. Blank values default to the local machine's hostname. Tested on Intellij Ultimate 2016.2. This is an issue with Intellij as jdb attaches fine.

Screenshot below of working settings:
[image]